# Does closing a question as a duplicate of a locked one makes sense?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicate-questions, locked-questions, historical-lock

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70020/is-there-any-other-way-to-determine-result-than-throwing-dice) has been closed by a moderator as a duplicate of [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7328/what-diceless-tabletop-rpg-techniques-are-there).

Is this really reasonable? Now even if I wanted to move my answer to the original question, I can't because it's locked. No one can improve the original post, and what's the point of linking people universally to something that might become outdated or in general doesn't serve as a good linking point?

The [meta discussion about the original](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1370/diceless-technique-question) had some voices about turning it into CW, which I think would be a much better option in this case.

While I've linked to a one particular SE site, I think the problem can be answered in a more general way, hence me asking here, not on Meta-RPG.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the closing mod on RPG.SE, that old question asks for all the methods of diceless resolution for tabletop games - there are very many, so that is too broad.

The new question is an exact duplicate of that one and therefore is closed as a dupe; I could close it on its own merits too of course but that would seem to lose context.

In the "general case," yes obviously you want to close questions as duplicates of locked questions if they are, you know, duplicates - by definition the new question would have the same issue the original locked one did. If there's concern over the close reason on the original question, that's a separate matter.

Comment: What about merging? If the answer on the new question is good, why not merge them and have the answer be part of the original, older, question? (then the newer can be safely deleted)

Comment: I could indeed merge Bartek's answer over, and was considering doing so, I had barely gotten done with the close part before this got escalated.  He could request that himself too, of course, and I find that taking additional steps like merging when the original person is griping about the mod activity already just makes it worse.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it makes sense.

It means the question being closed as duplicate is off topic, and should be closed anyway, as the lock banner of the special historical lock says:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but **it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site**

So, it's either just closing (and deleting) as off topic or closing as duplicate, which keeps the newer question alive and searchable.

As for the reason why it's off topic in the first place, MSE is not the proper place, and it's better be asked and/or discussed in the per site meta, e.g. in your example it would be https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/